# Некликабельные товары при поиске в Opencart

Tags: opencart

Всем добрый день!
Почему-то при некоторых запросах на сайте карточки товара некликабельны.. где-то в верхней части карточки только есть возможность нажать по всему остальному пространству некликабельно. Выявил что при вводе under armour или шапка такая история. Что это может быть, подскажите пожалуйста? Конфликт модулей или что-то другое?.. Модули последние отключил. И еще стили слетают при таких запросах.

https://abrams.com.ua/search/?search=under%20armour

https://abrams.com.ua/search/?search=%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что у Вас блок  находится в блоке со списком товаров и налазит на контент.

вам нужно вынести этот блок на уровень ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто у вас одна страница на http а вторая на https там где не защищенный протокол ошибки:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://abrams.com.ua/search/?search=%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://abrams.com.ua/image/catalog/products_new/original.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
>   ?search=шапка:2253 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://abrams.com.ua/search/?search=%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://abrams.com.ua/image/catalog/products_new/original.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Нужно поставить редирект на https в файле .htaccess [здесь пример](https://pai-bx.com/wiki/seo/80-301-redirect-from-http-to-https/), и ещё нужно будет в файле config.php изменить http на https